# Is there an efficient way to concatenate strings

Tags: go, concatenation, go-templates

For example, there is a function like that:

```
 func TestFunc(str string) string {
 return strings.Trim(str," ")
 }
```

It runs in the example below:

```
 {{ $var := printf "%s%s" "x" "y" }}
 {{ TestFunc $var }}
```

Is there anyway to concatenate strings with operators in template ?

```
 {{ $var := "y" }}
 {{ TestFunc "x" + $var }}
```

or

```
 {{ $var := "y" }}
 {{ TestFunc "x" + {$var} }}
```

It gives unexpected "+" in operand error.

I couldnt find it in documentation (https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is not a way to concatenate strings with an operator because Go templates do not have operators.

Use the `printf` function as shown in the question or combine the calls in a single template expression:

```
{{ TestFunc (printf "%s%s" "x" "y") }}
```

If you always need to concatenate strings for the TestFunc argument, then write TestFunc to handle the concatenation:

```
func TestFunc(strs ...string) string {
   return strings.Trim(strings.Join(strs, ""), " ")
}

{{ TestFunc "x"  $var }}
```

Comment: see also @gyoza https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template/issues/267#issuecomment-386416693